# Returning data from multiple ajax requests to a page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I know a version of this question has been asked, but I couldn't get find a solution that worked for me.

I have an array of routing numbers. I have to call an external service, retrieve the bank name associated with each and output them to a table. The routingnum.php returns the bankname wrapped in a routingnum function like this:  routingnum("WELLS FARGO BANK NA");

Here's what I tried:

```
<script>
  function getbankname(rnum) {
    var activeurl = "https://www.example.com/php/routingnum.php?rn=" + rnum + "&callback=routingnum";
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
      url: activeurl,
      jsonpCallback: 'routingnum',
      success: function (data) {
        var thisdiv = $("." + rnum);
        $(thisdiv).text(data);
      }
    });  
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var routingnumbers = ['325070760','323075356','121042882'];
    var ddcontent = "<tbody>";
    for (var i=0; i<routingnumbers.length; i++) {
      var rnum = netPayDistributionsDetail[i];
      getbankname(rnum);
      ddcontent +="<tr><td class=" + rnum + "></td><td>" + rnum + "</td></tr>";
    }
    ddcontent += "</tbody>";

    $(ddcontent).insertAfter("#accttable thead:nth-child(1)");  

 }); 
</script>


<table width="100%" id="accttable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Bank Name</th>
      <th class="data-format">Routing Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: edit -   var rnum = routingnumbers[i];

Comment: What is wrong with it now?

Comment: it doesn't return all 3 banknames consistently.   Sometimes it returns one, then when I refresh it returns all.   Then when i refresh the same name is returned multiple times etc

Comment: could you update your question and include a sample of routingnum.php output?

Comment: routingnum.php just returns the bankname, wrapped in a routingnum function.  sample output:

Comment: routingnum("WELLS FARGO BANK NA");

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you treat the response as text instead of json and omit the use of the callback function, instead, write your own success callback function that will extract the bank name, and insert it into the corresponding td using the routing number as the class name as follows:

```
  function getbankname(rnum) {
        var activeurl = "https://www.example.com/php/routingnum.php?rn=" + rnum; // omit the callback function in url
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'text', // <-- parse the data as text 
      contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8", // <-- parse the data as text 
      url: activeurl,
      // jsonpCallback: 'routingnum', // <-- remove this, use success callback instead as shown in next line
      success: function(data) {
       // read the bank name between 'rountingnum("' and '")' using substring
       // if you have control over routingnum.php output, modify it to  just  
       // print bank name directly and omit the use of substring
         var bankName = data.substring(12, data.length - 2);
        // update the corresponding td using rnum as class selector
        $("td." + rnum).html(bankName);
      }
    });
  }


  $(document).ready(function() {
    var routingnumbers = ['325070760', '323075356', '121042882'];
    var ddcontent = "<tbody>";
    for (var i = 0; i < routingnumbers.length; i++) {
      var rnum = routingnumbers[i];
      ddcontent += "<tr><td class=" + rnum + ">loading..</td><td class='bankName'>" + rnum + "</td></tr>";
      getbankname(rnum); // schedule ajax request for current rnum, at this point the bank name will display 
                         // loading.. until the request is fulfilled and success callback defined above is executed.
    }
    ddcontent += "</tbody>";
    $(ddcontent).insertAfter("#accttable thead:nth-child(1)");

  });
```

Comment: Thanks Shadi.  I'm getting this error, since the php is on a remote server

Comment: Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: Only script and json are the allowed data types for cross origin data, right?

Comment: I see, yes in this case the remote server denies application/text preflight request, in this case set  `contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8"` but leave  `dataType: 'text',` and it should work.

Comment: I changed data type to script and got it to work - thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Excellent, and my suggestion to parse the data as text is for security considerations, it's not a good practice to execute javascript code from remote sources unless you trust that source.